# Is there any graphical Binary Diff tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, binary, diff

Are there any Binary Diff tools for Mac OS X with a GUI? There are a gazillion text-based diff tools, but I need to compare two binary files. Essentially two Hex Editors with Dec/Hex View next to each other (the binary files are a custom file format, so not images or anything that has a more specialized diff tool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is Ellié Computing Merge (http://www.elliecomputing.com) (NB: I work for ECMerge).
it can compare arbitrarily large files with usual Hex+ASCII views and side by side visual diff.
it works on mac and linux/windows as well

Comment: It's an extremely clunky application, but it does have the possibility to configure the Binary comparison in the settings, which is a big plus (Hex Fiend doesn't do that)

Comment: Why does the UI look like its a relic from the 1970s, and why is the font so screwed up?

Comment: Lol, app crashed when I tried to diff a mere 5gb file.

Answer (score 209):

I just discoverd [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) – love at first sight! Open both binary files then do `File > Compare x and y` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[image: Hex Fiend]

Comment: in case you can't find how to do this - open both files and then under the "find" menu there is "compare x and x..." - this was not obvious to me at first.

Comment: File menu, not find menu.

Comment: Hex Fiend is awesome and open source. It can be used as a framework in your own app. I'm not affiliated, just a long-time user.

Comment: In case you still can't find it like me, please note the Compare feature is only available in Hex Fiend 2.1.2 and up, so make sure you have the latest version!

Comment: Open up both files, and then you will see the "Compare" option

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Yosemite 64-bit. App just crashes immediately.

Comment: TiP: Click on Hex Fiend address column to toggle between hex and decimal address numbers. ( using OS X 10.11.6 )
And the find data works well too!

Comment: @cwd, How does compare differ from comparerange?

Comment: @cwd, Why doesn't hexfield got a "move to applications folder" as typical of every other MAc app?

Comment: Available via Homebrew too! `brew install --cask hex-fiend`.

Answer (score 21):

You could store the hex of each binary in temp files, then compare *them* with `diff`. This would give you the visual hex difference.

```
xxd -c 1 file1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > file1.hex
xxd -c 1 file2 | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > file2.hex

diff file1.hex file2.hex
```

`xxd` creates a hex dump, and we're telling it to print one byte per line, then `cut` splits on space and compares the correct column

you could also use `od` instead of `xxd`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `colorbindiff.pl` it's a simple perl script that does exactly what you want, a side-by-side (and colored) binary diff. It shows byte changes and byte additions/deletions.

[image: colorbindiff output snapshot]

You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/jjazzboss/colorbindiff).

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Maybe ["HexEdit by Lane Roathe"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexedit/), wxHexEditor or UltraEdit

Comment: It's able to do diff? How?

Answer (score 1):

My go-to is for stuff like this is [010 Editor](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/).  It has a very customizable hex bin-diff, configurable min match length, synchronized scrolling, and much more.

[Beyond Compare 4](https://www.scootersoftware.com/) does a pretty good job, especially if you have multiple binary files to compare.  However, it's matching isn't obviously configurable and can be wonky, depending on the use-case.

Comment: Beyond compare dones't work for binary files above 0.5GB