# Copyright infringement detection

Tags: ios

When a customer decides to break a contract an use software they didn't pay for:
Is it possible to make a binary comparison with an app from app store with an ipa file based on your own software to detect if code that shouldn't be used is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming you can get hold of the ipa file you want to compare with your own (which could presumably be done by installing that app from the App Store onto a jail broken device).  You could than use (or write) a utility to compare that file with your own.

Here's an example of someone asking for a binary diff tool,

[Is there any graphical Binary Diff tool for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871702/is-there-any-graphical-binary-diff-tool-for-mac-os-x)

Of course, you would expect some differences (signing, timestamps, etc).  You'd need to look at the detail of the differences to decide on whether that file is fundamentally the same (or derived from the same source).

Comment: I have picked the ipa file apart now, but haven't been able to find the actual binary files.
After asking Apple about this issue.
Their response was that it is not a service that they provide.

Comment: I guess the file is encrypted.